# How to create standalone exe in clion?

Tags: c++, clion

When I try to run `.exe` from `cmake-build-debug` I have an error:

> "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll not found".

How to build standalone `.exe` without any `dlls`. I use `CLion 2017.2.4, MinGW 5.0, cmake 3.9.4`

Comment: this is probably more a cmake/mingw question than a clion one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did it.
To do this you need to add to the file `CMakeLists.txt` this line:

> set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc")

After this `CMakeLists.txt` shoud look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(MyProject${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Reload changes in `CMakeLists.txt`

Run -> Clean

Run -> Build

Now `.exe` file is standalone